# Why does the IME on my android application de-associate from the EditText it should be editing?

Tags: android, focus, android-layout, android-edittext, ime

I've got an Android application I'm writing.  It has a ListActivity in it that's all set up to load my data using this layout for each item.

My data Adapter binds with no problem and I've set it up so that when an item is selected from the list this method is called.

```
private void showPasswordBox(View v) {
 EditText passwordBox = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.hidden_box);
 Button passwordSubmit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hidden_box_submit);

 passwordSubmit.setText("Login");
 passwordSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 passwordBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

 passwordBox.setHint(R.string.password);
 passwordBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
 passwordBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This has the effect of displaying and EditText and a Button (hidden_box and hidden_box_submit in my layout). Which is just what I wanted.

However a problem occurs when the user taps on the newly visible EditText (hidden_box).  The IME pops up and hidden_box immediately loses focus.  Consequently anything typed on the IME does not appear in the EditText.  Instead it's doing this weird thing where anything typed appears above the keyboard in grey letters and remains at the bottom of the screen when the IME is dismissed.  It's like the IME is typing into it's own temporary invisible box.

If the user taps on the EditText after the IME is already showing then the application behaves as it should.  Anything typed on the IME appears in the EditText and remains when the IME is dismissed.

It seems to me that when the IME pops up (which it does immediately when the user taps on the EditText, as it should) it completely de-associates with my application and does its thing in IME la-la land unless I direct it to the EditText by tapping on the EditText before typing and dismissing the keyboard.  How do I make it behave normally so it types directly into the EditText as soon as it pops up?

Answer (score 0):

```
       passwordBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Hope this will work. Does it?

Comment: 'Fraid not.  My original code didn't have that line but I added it in the hopes that it would fix the problem.